# Indexing and querying CQL3 collection map in Solr

Tags: solr, cassandra, cql3, datastax-enterprise, datastax

The following [documentation page](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchSolrType.html?scroll=srchSolrType__map-cql-collections) from Datastax states:

```
DSE Search maps collections as follows:
     Collection list and set: multi-valued field
     Collection maps: dynamic field
The name of the dynamic field minus the wildcard is the map name. For example, a map column name dyna* is mapped to dyna. Inner keys are mapped to the full field name.
```

The last statement is not very clear to me. How exactly should the field definition look like? Assuming that I have a collection map defined as `scores map<int,int>` in CQL3, is the following field definition correct?

```
<field name="scores*" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

And how do I query this? Assuming that the map's value is `{201409 : 89, 201410 : 67}` and I want to filter on inner field '201410', is the following correct?:

```
fq=scores201410:[80 TO *]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the dynamic field minus the wildcard is the map name means that the following dynamic field corresponds to the following map name in CQL:

dynamic field: `<dynamicField name="lang_*" . . . >`
map name: `CREATE TABLE hits ( . . .lang_ map<text, text>, . . .);`

In your example, dynamic field name = scores_*.

The query depends on the values you insert into the fields. If you insert these values into the CQL scores_ column:

```
{ 'scores_100'  : '5000'}
 { 'scores_200'  : '10000'}
 { 'scores_100'  : '300'}
```

then, I think the query to get all the scores_100 in the collection would be:

http://:8983/solr/mykeyspace.myscores/select?q=scores_100%3A*&wt=xml&indent=true

Comment: Thanks! Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954157/how-do-i-see-solr-dynamic-fields-in-cql-with-cassandra (but your answer is more specific)

Comment: Ah, yes. The excellent answer to the related question contains something I failed to say: The dynamic part isn't inferred inside the map by the name of the container (the map). So you need to include the dynamic part in the data. This also means that the key part has to be a text type.