# Solr Aggregation / Facet on DynamicField

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise, datastax

Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE attributes_v1 (
  profile_id bigint,
  attributes map<text, int>,
  solr_query text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((profile_id))
)
```

Data inside the table looks like this:

```
profile_id | attributes                                  
------------+---------------------------------------------
          2 | {'a101': 1, 'a11': 1, 'a12322': 1, 'a51': 3}
          3 |      {'a1': 1, 'a10': 1, 'a11': 3, 'a51': 1}
          1 |     {'a1': 1, 'a10': 1, 'a2322': 1, 'a5': 3}
```

I can't figure out how to accomplish the following (using solr either via CQL or java)

Desired aggregation / facet :

a1 count: 2
a1 sum: 2

a101 count: 1
a101 sum: 1

a11 count: 2
a11 sum: 4

a12322 count: 1
a12322 sum: 1

a2322 count: 1
a2322 sum: 1

a10 count: 2
a10 sum: 2

a51 count: 2
a51 sum: 4

a5 count: 1
a5 sum: 3

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should have prefixed your map keys with the name of the field itself. This is a requirement/limitation as mentioned in the following links:

[link1](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchDynFlds.html)

[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26495491/indexing-and-querying-cql3-collection-map-in-solr)

[link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954157/how-do-i-see-solr-dynamic-fields-in-cql-with-cassandra)

So, for example, your 'a1' element should have been called 'attributes1' and your 'a12322' should have been called 'attributes12322'.

Then in your Solr schema, define a dynamicField as follows:

```
<dynamicField name="attributes*" ... />
```

You can then query the map elements by referring to them directly. e.g.

```
q=attributes12322:1
```

Now, for your question about aggregating, since you also need the sum aside from the count, I think you to use need `stats` instead of `facet`.

```
stats=true&stats.field=attributes12322
```

You can specify multiple stats.field parameters like:

```
stats=true&stats.field=attributes12322&stats.field=attributes1&stats.field=attribute51
```

You can then retrieve the sum from the 'sum' attribute and the count from the 'count' attribute of each stats_fields response item

EDIT:

I didn't notice immediately that you were specifically asking for querying Solr via CQL or Java. I'm not sure if 'stats' is supported by [CQL Solr queries](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchCql.html)